# Representing Deeply Nested Data in XML

Tags: xml, database, database-design

I have data of the following data schema:

```
Software
+
|
|  Microsoft
|   +
|   +--->Windows 10
+-->+
|   +--->Windows 7
|
| Google
|   +
|   +-->Chrome
+-->+
    +-->Orkut
```

I want to nest this optimally that is redable by any XML Parser, my initial idea was to do it like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<Software Name = "Company Software">
  <HeadProduct Name = "Google">
    <Product>Chrome</Product>
    <Product>Orkut</Product>
  </HeadProduct>
  <HeadProduct Name = "Microsoft">
    <Product>Windows 10</Product>
    <Product>Windows 7</Product>
  </HeadProduct>
</Software>
```

However, my gut tells me this is a problem and definitely not what I intended. Here is why:

While `Google` and `Microsoft` are just attributes, `Windows 10` and `Orkut` are elements. I my mind somewhere I would have liked `Google` and `Microsoft` as elements as well. To summarize, I don not think I have correctly translated the schema to XML.

Any help will be beneficial.

Comment: Any XML is readable by any XML parser, so that's not a good requirement because it's always going to be true. And what you view as "optimal" is highly subjective. There are XML structures that make more sense than others, but this is a) a continuum, not an absolute and b) it depends on so many factors that without context it's hard to decide what makes more sense in any given situation.

Comment: @Tomalak Honestly, I do not have a very complicated context. This is the reason behind my question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55472870/one-to-many-table-relationship

Comment: if i understand what you mean : ``...<HeadProduct Name = "Google">...`` to ``...<HeadProduct><Name>Google</Name>......``

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to avoid attributes, this may work for you.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<Software>
    <Name>Company Software</Name>
    <HeadProducts>
        <HeadProduct>
            <Name>Google</Name>
            <Products>
                <Product>Chrome</Product>
                <Product>Orkut</Product>
            </Products>
        </HeadProduct>
        <HeadProduct>
            <Name>Microsoft</Name>
            <Products>
                <Product>Windows 10</Product>
                <Product>Windows 7</Product>
            </Products>
        </HeadProduct>
    </HeadProducts>
</Software>
```